# Click function show(), after next click it disappears

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I'm experiencing problem - I got a function, when someone clicks a menu, it will show a div tag. See here -

```
$("a#cat").click(function() {
  $("div#categoryBox").show();
  return false;
});
```

So far everything works great, the div content shows up excellent, but the problem is that inside div content there are buttons (a tags), delete and edit, when I click one of these buttons, the div tag hides. The button links are -

```
<a href="?action=edit&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"> and <a href="?action=delete&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

If I press one of these links, the div content automatically hides, and I need to press again the a button with id #cat. Is there any way to make it stay, unless I press different menu link or refresh page?

If you need any additional information, please ask.

Comment: where is edit and delete click implementation?

Comment: What events are bound to the anchors in `div#categoryBox`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli and tandu - edit and delete are hyperlinks.  He posted the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Perhaps the easiest is to re-show the div when the page loads if certain conditions are met.

If you want to display the div every time the url is `?action=edit` or `?action=delete`, use this:

```
$(function () {
    if (/\baction=(edit|delete)\b/.test(location.search)) {
        $("div#categoryBox").show();
    }
});
```

Or, you could append a hash parameter when you want to show the div:

```html
<a href="?action=edit&id=<?php echo $id; ?>#showCategoryBox">edit</a>
<a href="?action=delete&id=<?php echo $id; ?>#showCategoryBox">delete</a>
```

```js
$(function () {
    if (location.hash === "#showCategoryBox") {
        $("div#categoryBox").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Or perhaps a big cleaner, show it initially from the backend if the parameter is present.

Comment: Hello, that is the way, that I needed :)! So for example If i add new one ?action=add, then it would look something like baction=(edit|delete|add)? did I understood correct?

Comment: @user1184908 - Yep, that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

May be the page is reloaded when you click on edit/delete links, so you think the div gets hidden. If you are doing any client side implementation on `edit` and `delete` click then you should make sure to prevent the default behavior or those links. Try this.

```
$('#categoryBox a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hello, after adding it, the delete and edit links are not working anymore (nothing shows up when i press delete and edit).

Comment: OP indicated the page is of necessity reloaded when the links are clicked because they are hyperlinks.  Preventing default will cause the links to not be opened, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Hello, then with this solution, I won't be able to click the links and they won't take any effect, correct?

Comment: @downvoter - My answer assumed the links have some client side implementation may be using ajax so my answer was based on that OP didn't mention it initially